# Play framework 2.5 not loading my application.conf in tests

Tags: playframework, guice, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to test my play app but I'm running into issues with DI. I've tracked it down to the fact that my `application.conf` file isn't being loaded by Guice.

I assume from the docs that if I use `GuiceApplicationBuilder` it should configure my application in the same way as when I run it, which would include loading my `application.conf`.

I literally just have `new GuiceApplicationBuilder().build()` in my test and I've set a breakpoint where Guice loads its modules and I can see that none of my config is in the configuration object, and my non-root module isn't in the list of enabled modules so isn't being loaded.

Do am I wrong? Do I need to manually tell it to load my `conf/application.conf` file? I based my project on the seed at https://github.com/playframework/play-isolated-slick/ so maybe this modular structure is causing issues?

One note is that I'm seeing a directory `application.home_IS_UNDEFINED`. Perhaps it's that this modular structure has messed up play's ability to set its home directory and therefore can't find `conf/application.conf` while testing (for some reason everything works correctly when I run my server).

Comment: Looks like it was loading an application.conf I created in the slick module's test directory so it wasn't loading the main one.

Comment: Note that you can configure the config to be loaded as resource, which means you can put it onto the classpath.

Comment: Have you tried loading your conf file explicitly by `ConfigFactory.load("confFile")` ?